# Como instanciar uma Activity com campos de EditText sem ficarem selecionados automaticamente?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment

Desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android, deparei com um problema, eu tenha uma Activity onde há campos de edição(EditText) no xml, e quando instancio ela, o primeiro campo EditText, fica selecionado e o teclado aparece pra preencher, e eu não queria que o teclado aparecesse, e q não selecionasse o campo automaticamente, basicamente to montando uma Activity inicial igual a de login do app da Evernote. E se tiver como passa os esquema de fazer aquela Activity com as TabLayout, ViewPager, e o parallax que ele faz melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude o foco para seu Layout, como no exemplo abaixo, retirado do **[SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup/8639921#8639921)**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma simples é no *AndroidManifest.xml* declarar a activity desta forma:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          .....
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
          >
```

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão o android sempre marca o que contem o input com `<autofocus/>` ou o primeiro, uma solução é no onCreate inserir o seguinte trecho:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(seuInputText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```